# Tabulator - problem with custom header filters and searchData()

Tags: tabulator

I am using searchData() to count rows under different conditions for display to the user, without affecting the table itself. Specifically one col is "available" and I want to show how many rows there are depending on the filter criteria set, for both available and unavailable states. Most filters are normal default type header filters.

To do this I use the dataFiltered() callback. Inside the callback I get all the filters in a list, then do a count with and without an "available" filter added to the list. The problem is that I have one column with a custom header filter, and Tabulator complains if this one is active when searchData() is called. The custom filter works as expected in the table. Relevant code snippets are:

```
//table def
    dataFiltered:function(filters, rows) { SetCounts(filters, rows) },
// col def
    {title:"Sex", field:"sex", visible:true, hozAlign:"center", headerSort:false,
        headerFilter:true, headerFilterFunc:customSexFilter,
    },

// custom filter
    function customSexFilter(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
        return (headerValue == rowValue) || (headerValue == "M" && rowValue == "N") || (headerValue == "F" && rowValue == "S");
    }

// dataFiltered callback (simplified; one of two cases shown)
    var availFilter = { field: "avail", type: "like", value: "A"};
    function SetCounts(filters, rows) {
        if (!table) return;
        var filt = table.getHeaderFilters().concat(filters.slice());
        var nAll = rows.length;
        var fA = filt.slice();
        fA.push( availFilter );
        var nAvail = table.searchData(fA).length;
        \$("#rowCount").html([nAll, '/', nAvail, 'A'].join(''));
    }
```

The error that I get is `Filter Error - No such filter type found, ignoring: function o(o)`
and the filter itself shows as

```
field: "sex"
type:o(o)
value: "F"
```

I've studied the docs but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Or is this not supported? Version 4.6.

Comment: Pretty sure the error is coming from searchData.  It seems to be choking on the filter type(o(o)). That is not one of the known types , '=' or '>=', etc. So what is the value of fA?

Comment: At that point fA is a list containing the sex filter shown, plus a "known" filter type for availability. I agree the issue is with searchData(); I concluded that filters are not completely compatible across all uses, which is awkward. Fortunately I was able to work around this by changing the sex column from a header filter to a table filter, in a format that is compatible with searchData().

Comment: What happens if you change headerFilter from true to 'input'?

Comment: Problem still exists if headerFilter is "input:.

Comment: If you believe you have found a bug, please report it on the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator)